# How to change the permissions that apache uses to write a file?

Tags: php, apache2, devops

I'm working with [Sximo](http://ultimate.sximo5.net/) that has the option to add modules through it's web interface. When you add a module it writes php files that has the functionality for that module.

I need to edit that php files with my own user, but obviously that files are written by `www-data` user.

I already set `APACHE_RUN_GROUP=web` in apache envars in order to uses the group `web` where my user is part of.

So the files results in:

`-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data web 5621 abr 11 12:43 sximo/modules/Mynewmodule.php`

My question is, if there is a way to say to apache that write the files with `+w` access to the group?

`-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data web 5621 abr 11 12:43 sximo/modules/Mynewmodule.php`

Comment: are the new files owned by apache ? issue is not clear ..for me !

Comment: yes, are owned by www-data which is the apache user. I want to apache write the files with write access to the group

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the owner of the target directory to the owner of apache.

Use

```
chown -R group:user target
```

Comment: Thanks @mkentaro, but that is not what I want. I want to apache write files with +w permissions to group. And as annotation is first the user then the group `chown -R  user:group target`